# How can I go back to an older version of numba

Tags: jupyter-notebook, numba

I just upgraded to numba 0.12 and now IPython notebook 'hangs' whenever I invoke a function decorated with @jit.

I would like to simply return to numba 0.11, which was working wonderfully.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Anaconda:

```
conda install numba=0.11.1
```